# How to Navigate within Category? Lot of codes here on stackexchange didn't work

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

At present I am using the below code to navigate between previous and next post.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
if (is_single()) {
    ?>
    <div class="prev-navigation">
        <?php previous_post_link('%link', '&Lang; &Lang; &Lang; %title') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="next-navigation">
        <?php next_post_link('%link', '%title &Rang; &Rang; &Rang;') ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

You can check this code at work on www.pmfias.com

Comment: Please can you update your question to specify what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [**`previous_post_link`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_post_link/) and [**`next_post_link`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/) accept a 3rd boolean parameter **$in_same_term**, which specifies whether link should be in a same taxonomy term.

So in your scenario you would be looking to make the following update:

[**previous_post_link**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_post_link/)

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link', '&Lang; &Lang; &Lang; %title') ?>
```

**updated to**

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link', '&Lang; &Lang; &Lang; %title', true) ?>
```

**and [next_post_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/)**

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', '%title &Rang; &Rang; &Rang;') ?>
```

**updated to**

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', '%title &Rang; &Rang; &Rang;', true) ?>
```